# Solr sort by min of two fields?

Tags: search, sorting, select, lucene, solr

I want to sort a result set by the minimum of several fields.

So after reading the functionquery documentation this is what I came up with:

```
sort={!func}min(dvd_available_from_tdt,dto_available_from_tdt)%20desc
```

I also tried:

```
sort=_val_:min(dvd_available_from_tdt,dto_available_from_tdt)%20desc

sort=_val_:"min(dvd_available_from_tdt,dto_available_from_tdt)"%20desc

sort=_val_:"min(dvd_available_from_tdt,dto_available_from_tdt)%20desc"

sort="{!func}min(dvd_available_from_tdt,dto_available_from_tdt)"%20desc

sort={!func}min(dvd_available_from_tdt,dto_available_from_tdt)%20desc

sort="min(dvd_available_from_tdt,dto_available_from_tdt)"%20desc
```

and also some other placements of the quotes. But no matter what I always get this error:

> HTTP ERROR: 400
>
> Missing sort order.

Can anyobody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a query that matches all documents, with a constant score, plus a function.

http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*+_val_:price&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&debugQuery=true

Also, upgrading to Solr 3.3 is not that painful, and there's all sorts of cool new toys like sorting by function.

Comment: nice idea! my problem is that the there are numerous factors taht can be applied and the query parser is dismax. i already wrote an update shell script that i will run tomorrow. am i right in the assumption that i can just copy the data directory and keep the index? are they fully compatible? my tests on a developement system did not show any errors so far.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be available only in solr 3.1. I am running 1.4.1

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function